# Custom SiteDefinition having List Instances,Visual webparts and Event Receivers

Tags: site-definition

Custom SiteDefinition  having List Instances,Visual webparts and Event Receivers how to mention this Feature ID's in Onet.XML any sample code?

Comment: what is this feature for ?

Answer (score 1):

> If its a list Feature, then you can add it in Configuration's  list
>   tag and if its site feature, you can add it to siteFeature's tag
>   within configuration

as explained in this MSDN Article

[MSDN article with explanation for ONET.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432370.aspx)

Hope it helped ;)